# How to check the relation of a row in database table to another table before performing any deletion on it?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql Database, I have a task that is,

> Any item should not get deleted if
>   they are already linked to any other
>   module’s item, if asked for deletion
>   same is the case for Active and
>   Inactive.

Now, the data base I Have is not at all normalised. So can this achieved?
 Could some help me out?

Comment: If you are using InnoDB, simply put a foreign key with RESTRICT on linking fields. If that's not an option, you need to check all related tables to see if matching items exist.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do something like this. You probably need an subquerry and EXISTS. Can you please post the tables involved?

Comment: @oliver there are 35 tables. do u think its good option to post those tables herein?

Comment: No but I hope you do not have to querry all 35 tables to find out if two items are linked. If you have to... could you give an example how yor items are linked? What kind of relation? Fo you use foreign keys or link tables? Just give us some mor information about your database structure.

Comment: @Oliver if this is the case.. Then I understood the point of linking the tbls and restricting the actions.. thanks Any ways...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is to use  [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html), 
another option if you have innodb engine tables 
 [ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)